# How to extract the useful data with regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which is

```
<a href="/KB/ajax/" id="ctl00_MC_TCRp_ctl01_TSRp_ctl01_TSNL">Ajax</a>
```

now I want to get /KB/ajax/ and Ajax with Regex Class in C#.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Cheers

Comment: Provide the string and what you want to get

Comment: You might consider using an XML parser for this instead. This is what they're for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string url = "<a href=\"/KB/ajax/\" id=\"ctl00_MC_TCRp_ctl01_TSRp_ctl01_TSNL\">Ajax</a>";

Regex finder = new Regex("href=\"([^\"]*)\"");
string first = finder.Match(url).Groups[1].Value;

finder = new Regex(">([^<]*)<");
string second = finder.Match(url).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: can anyone explain this answer please.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex also allows for tags inside the text enclosed by `<a>...</a>`:

```
<\s*a\b[^>] href\s*=\s*['"]([^"']*)['"][^>]*>((?:.(?!</a))*.)</a
```

C#.NET Code Example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@"\<\s*a\b[^\>]+href\s*=\s*['""]([^""']*)['""][^\>]*\>((?:.(?!<\/a))*.)\<\/a");
          MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
          int mIdx=0;
          foreach (Match m in mc)
           {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
              }
            mIdx++;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

$matches Array:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="/KB/ajax/" id="ctl00_MC_TCRp_ctl01_TSRp_ctl01_TSNL">Aj<b>a</b>x</a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /KB/ajax/
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aj<b>a</b>x
        )

)
```

Comment: very powerful reg exp, and I learnt how to use MatchCollection, thanks Daniel :)